# The touchpad can support a better bus than the too old PS/2 protocol

Tags: touchpad

I am not sure about what I should do to implement the following dmesg "suggestion"

```
[    4.005445] psmouse serio1: synaptics: The touchpad can support a better 
bus than the too old PS/2 protocol. Make sure MOUSE_PS2_SYNAPTICS_SMBUS and 
RMI4_SMB are enabled to get a better touchpad experience.
```

How to proceed to enable the two options?

I am on Debian Stretch (the machine is an X1 Carbon 5th generation [yes, the one with the touchpad issue]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are kernel build options.

The simplest option (but the one which involves waiting the longest) is to file a bug against the Debian Linux kernel package, asking for those options to be enabled:

```
reportbug linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

(Please do this anyway, to ensure the options are enabled eventually for all Debian users.)

You can also build your own kernel, with the appropriate configuration changes; see the instructions in the [Debian kernel handbook](http://kernel-handbook.alioth.debian.org/ch-common-tasks.html#s-common-building). Once you’re running `make nconfig`, you’ll find the relevant configuration settings under Device Drivers, Input device support, then:

- Mice, PS/2 mouse, Synaptics PS/2 SMbus companion (for `MOUSE_PS2_SYNAPTICS_SMBUS`);
- Synaptics RMI4 bus support, RMI4 SMB Support (for `RMI4_SMB`).