# X1 Carbon 5th Generation (Debian 9) touchpad issue

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad

The new X1-Carbon has a touch pad issue: the pointer freezes once every now and then for 3-4 seconds. dmesg shows

```
psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
```

There are quite a few discussions on this

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/forums/v3_1/forumtopicpage/board-id/Special_Interest_Linux/thread-id/9645/page/1

https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/6097ac/x1_carbon_5th_error_touchpad_lost_sync_at_byte_1/

but it does not seem that there is a working solution for everybody (actually, it seems that almost nobody managed to solve the problem). I was wondering whether somebody has a suggestion here to fix the issue (which does not occur very often, but it is extremely annoying).

What could it be the cause of this awkward behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here. The first is addressed in [The touchpad can support a better bus than the too old PS/2 protocol](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/402688/86440) (as you’re aware of course): the touchpad works much better using RMI4 rather than the old PS/2 protocol. The second is that the touchpad ideally should use a newer version of SMBus, but that needs some support from the kernel which isn’t there yet. There are very recent [patches available](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-input/msg53813.html), and the Fedora kernel [has them](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1509461), but I don’t think the Debian kernel has them yet. Presumably they’ll end up in 4.14 or 4.15 and hopefully will be backported to the stable kernels.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think that using the new protocol will work then? It was not mentioned in what I read in the two links I posted.

Comment: That’s what my colleagues tell me, and they checked with Synaptics engineers...